# Bootstrap width does not work on .NET Core 6

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I tried everything, from documentations, last 10 stack overflow answers, and nothing helped. I tried with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I tried with @@meedia in style, I tried with w-100 on card body, everything and nothing helps. I need whole application like this to have normal width so please help. I have VS 2022 with .NET 6 onboard.

I just cannot make when I start an application (on desktop) and go on F12, put on mobile. The card-body is really long and I want to set width of card-body to mobile screen size. i DO NOT KNOW where is the problem ...

Code is this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
        <div class="card-body">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaKuce">Prodaja kuća</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
        <div class="card-body">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaStanova">Prodaja stanova</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="card bg-light w-100 p-0">
        <div class="card-body">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Oglas" asp-action="ProdajaNekretninaZaOdmor">Prodaja nekretnina za odmor</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the final result is still the same. Yup.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

Two things, the first one, you need to add `m-0` in `<div class="row m-0">`.
The second one, you have forget a `</div>` at the end of you source code here upper for close the `div` for the `row`.

**Edit :**

In general, for debug CSS problems, you best friend is the inspector of the web browser.
With this one you can :

- Do a right click on the element of you page then click on Inspect.
- In the bottom left side, you see the HTML code and the selected element.
- In the bottom middle side, you see all CSS for the selected HTML element.
- In the bottom right side, you can see the box model with the margin, padding and size.

[image: Inspector web browser]

It's a really helpful tool for debugging HTML/CSS.

Comment: Yea, I closed the div and did not change anything. I also added m-0 in row and I have exactly the same result like in the first post.

Comment: Ok, strange because it works perfectly by me. Can you please post you `_Layout.cshtml` as well, especially the part with the `@RenderBody()` call? And can you please check which version of bootstrap you use? You can find that under `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\LICENCE` or somethings like that.

Comment: Wow, I just saw that I have: 

    <div class="container" style="width: 900px;">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget do click on the upper arrow on the answer. Regards.